# Joining 2 dataframes in pyspark where one column can have duplicates

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with 2 columns, `ID` and `condition`. ID corresponds to a user, the user can have multiple conditions. I want to find out those users who have condition A and condition B, how to do that?

Sample dataframe:

| ID | CONDITION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | D |
| 1 | E |

If I want to get users who have A,B as conditions, I need only 1 as the output.
If I want to get users who have C,D as conditions, I need only 2 as the output.
If I want to get users who have B,C as conditions, I need both 1 and 2 as outputs.

These requirements are represented in a dataframe as below:

| sl_no | conditions |
| --- | --- |
| s1 | [A,B] |
| s2 | [C,D] |
| s3 | [B,C] |

My attempt is as following:

```
       df1=df.groupBy('USER_ID').agg(F.collect_set('CONDITION').alias('conditions'))

       df2=conditions_data

       result=df1.join(df2,F.array_intersection(df1['conditions'],df2['conditions'])==df2['conditions'])
```

However, I see some inconsistencies in the results. Also, wanted to know if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the unique conditions per ID

```
users = df1.groupby('ID').agg(F.collect_set('CONDITION').alias('CONDITION'))

# +---+------------+
# | ID|   CONDITION|
# +---+------------+
# |  1|[C, E, B, A]|
# |  2|   [C, B, D]|
# +---+------------+
```

Join the conditions_data with the users dataframe where the join condition must satisfy the set membership test

```
cond = F.expr("size(array_intersect(conditions, CONDITION)) = size(conditions)")
result = conditions_data.join(users, on=cond, how='left')

# +-----+----------+---+------------+
# |sl_no|conditions| ID|   CONDITION|
# +-----+----------+---+------------+
# |   s1|    [A, B]|  1|[C, E, B, A]|
# |   s2|    [C, D]|  2|   [C, B, D]|
# |   s3|    [B, C]|  1|[C, E, B, A]|
# |   s3|    [B, C]|  2|   [C, B, D]|
# +-----+----------+---+------------+
```

Collect the users for each unique row in condition_data

```
result = result.groupby(*conditions_data.columns).agg(F.collect_list('ID').alias('ID'))

# +-----+----------+------+
# |sl_no|conditions|    ID|
# +-----+----------+------+
# |   s1|    [A, B]|   [1]|
# |   s2|    [C, D]|   [2]|
# |   s3|    [B, C]|[1, 2]|
# +-----+----------+------+
```